# Terminate all connections from specific schema in certain database

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, schema

With this command I can terminate all connections running in a specific database.

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'DATABASE_NAME' 
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Is there a way to terminate connections in a certain schema only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [PostgreSQL connections](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-connect.html) are always to a database, not to a schema.

Related question on dba.SE:

- [Force drop db while others may be connected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11893/3684)